# autorotate the Ipad only not iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am working on an app, where app is required to auto-rotate in Ipad only(i.e Landscape and the Potrait mode), which am able to achieve. But the Iphone one is not required to rotate(i.e. potarit mode only). I tried almost every code available on stackoverflow. but no success. 
I tried following

```
(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

and

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

but no success. I am also using NVSlider(a third party) for the slide bar. I wrote the code in that file also, as it was too having some orientation related methods, but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got the answer. as I was building a Universal app, I was provided with some option. See the images and we can set orientation for IPad and Iphone seprately. [image: options selected for the ipad only]

[image: options selected for iphone only]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

return YES;}
```